# Arrays aggregation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Assuming [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) available, all objects of the next [json](/questions/tagged/json) **arrays** have the same *length* and follow strictly the *schema* respectively indicated as follow

---

#### Array 1

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Etsy",
    "Link": "https://angel.co/etsy?utm_source=companies"
  },

  ...

]
```

#### Array 2

```
[
  {
    "Market": "Handmade"
  },

  ...

]
```

#### Array 3

```
[
  {
    "Website": "http://www.etsy.com"
  },

  ...

]
```

#### Array 4

```
[
  {
    "Employee": "-"
  },

  ...

]
```

#### Array 5

```
[
  {
    "Stage": "-"
  },

  ...

]
```

#### Array 6

```
[
  {
    "Raised": "$97,250,000"
  },

  ...

]
```

---

## Question:

What is the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) way using the cited arrays above as input to yield the array of the same *length* whose *schema* is like below?

---

#### Array Output

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Etsy",
    "Link": "https://angel.co/etsy?utm_source=companies",
    "Market": "Handmade"
    "Website": "http://www.etsy.com",
    "Employee": "-",
    "Stage": "-",
    "Raised": "$97,250,000"
  },

  ...

]
```

Comment: You might have better luck with underscore. jQuery provides basic looping and nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they all have the same length, you can map the first array and extend the objects inside

```
var result = array1.map(function(o, i) {
    return $.extend({}, o, array2[i], array3[i], array4[i], array5[i], array6[i]);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fx5thbfk/1/)